# Realtime update the Message board on website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I want to have a function that when the user write a comment on message board. User can see the message board update right away without refresh the website, like facebook!

I am new to JS and Ajax, and I found some ways to realize it as bellow. Is there any simple method or API to realize it?

I am totally new. Any advise will be helpful.

I use PHP before btw.

> 1.Ajax
>
> 2.[ezcomet](http://ezcomet.com/)
>
> 3.[Pusher](http://pusher.com/#/lang=undefined)
>
> 4.Comet
>
> 5.[ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You would use ajax or websockets(for games or real time apps). I don't know what 2 and 3 are. I think comet is a library. Message boards usually refresh the page because they are slow. I think your talking about a social network.